# how to select exactly part of a number as a simple character and exclude all the rest in CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

i will explain below what i want to do with CMD

I have this name of file:

```
set "File=0119315314"
```

with 2 in 2, i want to separete file name as this line: 01 19 31 53 14

the problem here, is the number 31 because of "53" and "14"
when its joined, we have "5314" and looks the mirror of "31" into "5314"

i tryed it:

```
set "New=%File:31=%"
```

when i exclude the number "31" I burn the characters "5314" too
now, i dont get "53" and "14" for my sequence: 01 19 31 53 14

you undestand? Please, how to solve it? is possible?

Comment: Not really understanding your explanation at all.  No idea what you mean by burn and mirror.  If you want to capture every two characters then use a substring of the existing variable. `set "var1=%File:~0,2%"` and `set "var2=%File:~2,2%"`, etc, etc...

Comment: Thanks so much! its more easy! Now I did a loop to generate the next number and to use two strings as one string, I used setlocal. Its Solved! thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "f=0119315314"

Set "i=0"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /U/D/C Echo(!f!^|%__AppDir__%find.exe /V ""') Do (
    Set /A "i+=1, m=i%%2"
    If !m! Equ 0 (Set "s=!s!%%G ") Else Set "s=!s!%%G")
If %m% Equ 0 Set "s=%s:~,-1%"

Echo(%s%

Pause
```

Expected result:

```batch-file
01 19 31 53 14
```

---

Or perhaps you're looking for something a little simpler:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "f=0119315314"

For /L %%G In (0,2,20) Do If Not "!f:~%%G,2!" == "" Echo(!f:~%%G,2!

Pause
```

Expected output:

```batch-file
01
19
31
53
14
```

In this example you can increase `20` if you intend to use a string of more than twenty characters.

Answer (score 0):

I read upto *"with 2 in 2, i want to separete file name as this line: 01 19 31 53 14"* line, because the rest is nonsense...

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "File=0119315314"
set "new="

:next
set "new=%new% %file:~0,2%" & set "file=%file:~2%" & if defined file goto next

echo %new:~1%
```

Output:

```
01 19 31 53 14
```

This method can separate any number of digits pairs; just put they in "File" variable...